# How to compress all files from several subfolders?

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zip, compression

Raw input：

```
    ➜  test tree
    .
    ├── f1.md
    ├── f2.md
    ├── f3.md
    ├── f4.txt
    ├── f5.csv
    ├── f6.doc
    ├── s1
    │   ├── code
    │   └── data
    │       ├── f1.md
    │       ├── f2.md
    │       ├── f3.md
    │       ├── f4.txt
    │       ├── f5.csv
    │       └── f6.doc
    ├── s2
    │   ├── code
    │   └── data
    │       ├── f1.md
    │       ├── f2.md
    │       ├── f3.md
    │       ├── f4.txt
    │       ├── f5.csv
    │       └── f6.doc
    ├── s3
    │   ├── code
    │   └── data
    │       ├── f1.md
    │       ├── f2.md
    │       ├── f3.md
    │       ├── f4.txt
    │       ├── f5.csv
    │       └── f6.doc
    └── s4
        ├── code
        └── data
            ├── f1.md
            ├── f2.md
            ├── f3.md
            ├── f4.txt
            ├── f5.csv
            └── f6.doc

    12 directories, 30 files
```

Expected output

```
➜  test tree
.
├── f1.md
├── f2.md
├── f3.md
├── f4.txt
├── f5.csv
├── f6.doc
├── s1
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       ├── f1.md
│       ├── f2.md
│       ├── f3.md
│       ├── f4.txt
│       ├── f5.csv
│       └── f6.doc
├── s2
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       ├── f1.md
│       ├── f2.md
│       ├── f3.md
│       ├── f4.txt
│       ├── f5.csv
│       └── f6.doc
├── s3
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── f1.md
│       ├── f2.md
│       ├── f3.md
│       ├── f4.txt
│       ├── f5.csv
│       └── f6.doc
└── s4
    ├── code
    └── data
        ├── Archive.zip
        ├── f1.md
        ├── f2.md
        ├── f3.md
        ├── f4.txt
        ├── f5.csv
        └── f6.doc

12 directories, 33 files
```

I want files from subfolders(s1/s2/s4) to compress.

I tried to use command-line `zip -r Archive.zip  ./*` in each subfolder( s1/s2/s4) . It's inconvenient because I have to enter same commands for three times.

How do I using a command once or writing a script to achieve this? I'm on OSX(10.12.6).

Comment: Just to confirm, you want to create `Archive.zip` in each `sX/data/` directory. What exactly is in `Archive.zip`? Also, what happens to the current contents of `Archive.zip`.

Comment: All files  including hidden ones. So I use `zip -r Archive.zip  ./*` command as mentioned.

Comment: `zip -r Archive.zip ./*` would _not_ include hidden files (unless you enable some `dotglob` option in some shells). You'd want `zip -r Archive .` for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this script can do the work:

```
for i in `find /path -type d -name data`;
do
if [ "$i" = "s3/data" ]
 then continue
 else cd "$i" && zip Archive.zip *
fi
done
```

P.S. Replace `/path` with starting point of your directory tree

Comment: Thanks and it works. I replace `/path` with `/Users/XXX/Desktop/try/test`( XXX：my Mac account) but is there a simple way to represent the `\path`?

Comment: Why it is so complicated!? Rather use `tar cvf file.tar *` :(

Comment: @JoshuaSalazar, you should exclude `s3/data` folder

Answer (score 5):

```
find . -type d -name data -execdir zip -jr data/Archive.zip data ';'
```

This `find` command will find each `data` directory under the current directory and execute

```
zip -jr data/Archive.zip data
```

in each of the `sN` directories (the parent directory of the `data` directories). This will also archive hidden files.

The `-j` flag to `zip` will strip the pathnames of the files added to the archive and the archive will be placed inside the `data` directory.

This works because `-execdir` basically does a `cd` to the parent directory of the found thing before executing the command.

To avoid the `s3` directory, use

```
find . -type d -name data \! -path "./s3/*" -execdir zip -jr data/Archive.zip data ';'
```

Answer (score 3):

POSIXly (except for the `zip` command obviously):

```
find . -path ./s3 -prune -o -type d -name data -exec sh -c '
   for dir do
     (cd "$dir" && zip -r Archive.zip .)
   done' sh {} +
```

Or with `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
for dir (./**/data~*/s3/*(/N)) (cd $dir && zip -r Archive.zip .)
```

Or if you don't want to search recursively for `data` folders:

```
for dir (./^s3/data(/N)) (cd $dir && zip -r Archive.zip .)
```

Or to be even more specific (no need for `extendedglob` here):

```
for dir (s[124]/data(/N)) (cd $dir && zip -r Archive.zip .)
```