# How to compress all files from all subfolders if there is no `Archive.zip` in subfolder？

Tags: shell-script, command-line, zip, compression

## Rawinput:

```
➜  datatest tree
.
├── a
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       └── apple.csv
├── archive.sh
├── f
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       ├── a.csv
│       ├── b.xlsx
│       └── c.xlsx
└── toolbox
    └── tool.py

7 directories, 9 files
```

## Output:

```
➜  datatest tree
.
├── a
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       └── apple.csv
├── archive.sh
├── f
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── code
│   └── data
│       ├── Archive.zip
│       ├── a.csv
│       ├── b.xlsx
│       └── c.xlsx
└── toolbox
    └── tool.py

7 directories, 10 files
```

In each /data subfolder, files should be compressed to `Archive.zip` except it already exists `Archive.zip`(like `f` folder).

## Trying:

I have to check if there is no `Archive.zip` in any `/data` subfolder by using `tree` command-line, then `zip -r Archive.zip  ./*` , which is inconvenient.

## Hope:

How do I using a command once or writing a script to achieve this? I'm on OSX(10.12.6).

Comment: What was wrong with the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388259/how-to-compress-all-files-from-several-subfolders#comment691256_388259) that was posted to your almost identical question: [How to compress all files from several subfolders?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/388259/how-to-compress-all-files-from-several-subfolders#comment691256_388259)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this maybe?

```
find . -type d -name data \
    \! -exec test -f {}/Archive.zip ';' \
    -execdir zip -rj data/Archive.zip data ';'
```

This would locate each `data` directory (first line).

The `\! -exec test -f {}/Archive.zip ';'` would filter out any `data` directory that does not contain any file called `Archive.zip`.

This line may be replaced by `\! -execdir test -f data/Archive.zip ';'`.

The last `-execdir` would execute the given `zip` command from within the parent directory of the `data` directory.  This would create `data/Archive.zip` containing the files in `data` (with no path attached to the archived filenames).

This is similar to [my answer to your previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/388277/116858), but with the test for existance of `data/Archive.zip` inserted.

Comment: Minor improvement: it might be cleaner to replace both `-exec` and `-execdir`  with a single command, `-execdir 'sh -c "[ -f data/Archive.zip ] || zip -rj data/Archive.zip data" sh'`.

Comment: @SatōKatsura That would probably be possible. If it's cleaner or not is debatable :-)